# Is there any way to partially include external resources in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, materialize

I was wondering whether there is any way to "partially" include an external resource in HTML/CSS. 
I got this idea when I tried to include Materialze.css in my project and I already had Bootstrap included. Materiliaze messed up my navigation bar as there were certain classes that shared their name between these two frameworks. The thing is I don't want to give up on any of them so I was curious if there is an actual way to only include one of them when is is needed.

Comment: Remove the conflicting classes from your Materialize.css that you don't want to load. There isn't really a way to selectively load styles they either load or they don't, this decision has to be made before run time.

Comment: What is the easiest way to do that?Or do I have to manually choose each one of them?

Comment: Manually choose them, and comment them out so you remember what you removed rather than deleting them entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `@import` to import fonts from the internet to css.
If you want to include scripts and stylesheets from files, use `<style src="materialize.css"><style>` or `<script src="hey.js"></script>`

P.s. I hope could answer your question, please explain what partial is in detail, cause i didnt understand what "partial" is? THank you